# No stamp when entering France from UK

Tags: passport-stamps

We moved to France last August. We come by car and the officers (both British and French) didn't stamp any of the passports.

Now we are applying for my wife's residence permit - because she's not European - and was wondering if they will complain about the missing stamp. My wife doesn't have a proof for the entry date.

Will this be a problem? She already have a UK permanent residence permit.

I am Italian and my wife is from Mauritius. We both have indefinite leave to remain in the UK.

Comment: Please supply the **relevent** information needed to answer  this question properly, such as citizenship of **both** parties and exactly what **type** of UK residence permit your wife has.

Comment: Are you an EU citizen?

Comment: Am not sure about this particular border, but this is a common practice at US-Canada road borders. Passports are not stamped.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the specific UK residence document will tell us whether the border officers were supposed to stamp her passport or not, but even if they were supposed to have stamped it, there is no adverse consequence for her application for a French residence card (assuming that algiogia is an EU citizen, which seems fairly safe to assume).

Comment: @BhushanKale I am fairly sure that US and Canadian practice at the land border varies depending on the nationality of the traveler.  The same is true between the UK and France.

Comment: @phoog If the wife has an Article 10 card, then the passport will not be stamped and is of no consequence for the French application.

Comment: @MarkJohnson even if the wife has some other card and the passport was supposed to be stamped, the lack of a stamp will be of no consequence for the French application.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that your wife isn't European, so I will assume that you are.

In this case, you should be applying for a residence card issued pursuant to the free movement directive, and in that case the absence of an entry stamp is of little consequence.  The one related factor is that the application costs €25 if she has been in the country for less than three months, and €340 if she has been there for longer.  So you will want to be able to prove that she was outside of France at some point, but you can use any evidence for that (and I suppose your statement of her date of arrival is probably going to be sufficient).